# How to clear clipboard in using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to clear my clipboard after copying stuff. Is this possible?

I tried using clipboard and paperclip, but they don't have clear methods.
https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/#description

Comment: Maybe `pyperclip.copy('')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just copy an empty string: `pyperclip.copy('')`

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Windows

```
from ctypes import windll
if windll.user32.OpenClipboard(None):
    windll.user32.EmptyClipboard()
    windll.user32.CloseClipboard()
```

No external libraries needed.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the suggested `pyperclip.copy('')` won't work. You have to add something instead of using an empty string, for example, use a white space: `pyperclip.copy(' ')`.